# select collection and get the last item of each in other collection in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I subscribed to the publication with the code below. So in my server side file,

```
Meteor.publish('people', function() {
    cursor = EmailDB.find({category:{$ne:"Spammer"}},{sort:{"lastMessage.date": -1},limit:20});
        let transformData = (fields) => {
                // this is the person we're processing now
                let eadd = fields.eadd;

                // get the latest message for this person
                key.eadd = eadd;
                let lastMessage = MessageDB.findOne(key,
                    {
                        sort: {date: -1}
                    }
                );

                // add his last message to the returned data
                fields.lastMessage = lastMessage;

                return fields;
            };

            let handle = cursor.observeChanges({
                added: (id, fields) => {
                fields = transformData(fields);
            this.added('emails', id, fields);
        },
            changed: (id, fields) => {
                fields = transformData(fields);
                this.changed('emails', id, fields);
            },
            removed: (id) => {
                this.removed('emails', id);
            }
        });

            this.ready();

            this.onStop(() => {
                handle.stop();
        });
        return cursor;
}
```

It get all the records of Person.
I want to get the latest message of each person.
So I used the code above but it is not working, It does not add additional fields to my query.

I need to just subscribe and fetch all records, and in each record there must be a last message.

Comment: you'll need to give me an example of your document, do you use ObjectId as you _id?

Comment: Yes.Only on the person collection. The message collection, not.

Comment: This is not yet solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever you want to join data from 2 published collections like this, you have a choice of doing it on the client or on the server. if you do it on the client, you've created a race condition for yourself. it can be solved, but i find it's cleaner and easier to do it on the server. and it makes it dead simple on the client, since you need to subscribe to only one collection.

so to do it on the server, you can take care of it in the publish. there, you can transform a returned collection (PersonDB) and add data to it (MessagesDB).

i don't know what your collections look like, or how they're named, so i'm obviously making some assumptions here.

```
Meteor.publish('people', function() {
    let cursor = PersonDB.find({});

    let transformData = (fields) => {
        // this is the person we're processing now
        let personId = fields.personId;

        // get the latest message for this person
        let lastMessage = MessagesDB.findOne({personId: personId},
            {
                sort: {createdAt: -1}
            }
        );

        // add his last message to the returned data
        fields.lastMessage = lastMessage;

        return fields;
    };

    let handle = cursor.observeChanges({
        added: (id, fields) => {
            fields = transformData(fields);
            this.added('personsdb', id, fields);
        },
        changed: (id, fields) => {
            fields = transformData(fields);
            this.changed('personsdb', id, fields);
        },
        removed: (id) => {
            this.removed('personsdb', id);
        }
    });

    this.ready();

    this.onStop(() => {
        handle.stop();
    });
});
```

on the client, you can subscribe to PersonDB like normal, and do the find like normal, and on each record you'll now have a "lastMessage" field appended.

Comment: What will I return?

Comment: i don't understand your question. do you mean what will you return from the publish i wrote above? nothing, it should work as i've written it.

Comment: I used "return cursor" or "return PersonDB.find({})". I subscribed. but the problem now is the latest message is not added to each item.

Comment: @JohnArellano, update your question with your code as it is now.

Comment: @JohnArellano, i simply guessed that you called your collection "personsdb". is that actually what it's called? if not, the added, changed, and removed listeners will never be called.

Comment: ah okay. My collection called is "emails".

Comment: How can I sort by lastMessage.date?

Comment: @JMA, the 2nd param of find() allows you to sort. e.g. Emails.find({}, {sort: {'lastMessage.date': 1});

Comment: I updated my codes. I used that line of code but still not working.

Comment: I will use sorting in the messages so i will get most recent persons I messaged.

Comment: IT is fixed Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the PersonDB Id in MessagesDB (if it is not the case)

```
MessagesDB.find({PersonDB:PersonDB._id},{limit:1}).fetch()[0]
```

Comment: What about if I added a filter in the PersonDB? For example, I want to get list of persons that are created today?

Comment: You can do PersonDB.find({createdAt: new Date()}).fetch()